# Any virtualization solutions freely available for "desktop integration"?

Tags: virtualization

[image: http://mac.elated.com/wp-content/uploads/vmware-applications-menu-300x119.png]

I'm looking for a solution where a guest VM can "integrate" to the host, e.g. I can start Internet Explorer 6 if I needed from the guest VM. I think VMware Fusion has something like this - are there any free/open source solutions for this?

Comment: Which Host OS? Anything specific?

Comment: I'm assuming it's Windows XP guest on Mac OS X host.

Comment: If it was a Windows 7 host then I believe this kind of functionality is in the Windows XP Mode that is available in Business and Ultimate editions.  Don't know about Mac OS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) has support for [seamless windows](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#seamlesswindows) with the appropriate Guest Additions, which are supplied for Windows guests.  The guest menu bars (such as taskbar and Start menu) are nested inside the host desktop.

Answer (score 2):

[VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) (free) offers Unity mode which is the "seamless" app running you're looking for. Available for Linux and Windows.